# in-text citation in sharelatex beamer presentation template

Tags: beamer, citing

I want to use some in-text citation in the beamer.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width=8.5cm,compat=1.9}

\usetheme{default}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
Einstein-Maxwell field equation........
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]
  \frametitle<presentation>{Bibliography}

  \begin{thebibliography}{10}

  \beamertemplatebookbibitems


  \bibitem{Tolman, R. C. 1939}
    Tolman, R. C.
    \newblock {\em On massive stellar cores}.
    \newblock Phys. Rev., 55, 364, doi:\href{http://dx.doi.org/10.1103/PhysRev.55.364}{10.1103/PhysRev.55.364}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

If I want to use the Tolman citation after the Einstein-Maxwell field equation line, then what should be the command? \cite{Tolman, R.C. 1939} does not work. Please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your key needs to include only allowed characters such as regular letters, numbers etc.

For example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{default}
\begin{document}
  \begin{frame}
    Einstein-Maxwell field equation\dots \cite{tolman1939}
  \end{frame}
  \begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]
    \frametitle<presentation>{Bibliography}
    \begin{thebibliography}{10}
      \beamertemplatebookbibitems
      \bibitem{tolman1939}
      Tolman, R. C.
      \newblock {\em On massive stellar cores}.
      \newblock Phys. Rev., 55, 364, doi:\href{http://dx.doi.org/10.1103/PhysRev.55.364}{10.1103/PhysRev.55.364}
    \end{thebibliography}
  \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

correctly produces a citation linking to the relevant entry in the bibliography:

[image: citation]